# access denied while requesting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

help my, cant connect to online database
heres's my connection php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "databasename";
$username = "database username";
$password = "database password";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

i already using database username and password same as cpanel provide, and all plain text with no symbol for password, but for the username and db name its always contain underscore

Example databasename and user

> example_dbname

> example_dbuser

and its say at error log like this

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '*example_user*'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in *path*/koneksi.php on line 8
```

the word between stars (*) i change for secure,

beside that, i already give the user all privilege for the database,
i already try the username and the password for cpanel its self but still access denied

note: its my own website, its mean i am freely to change up whatever in cpanel menu

Comment: add user to your database in cpanel

Comment: already added, and give the privilege, but still give access denied

Comment: is it free hosting ?